# Fix on python for loop on json.dumps not printing the full list provided

Tags: python, json, for-loop

Hi I am trying to create json code using json.dumps in python. I have a list of IP address that are read and put into a list. I am trying to loop through the list of IPs and create multiple addresses. The problem I am having is that it does the json.dumps with the last result of the for loop rather then the full list.

Here is my code:

```
with open ('example_file.txt', 'r') as ip_list: #provide the path of the local file that stores the ip addresses
    ip_address = [line.rstrip() for line in ip_list] # Puts the ips in a list 

for each_ip in ip_address:
    gateway_dict = {'type': 'RANGE', 'value': (each_ip + '-' + each_ip)}
    json.dumps(gateway_dict)

print(gateway_dict)
```

example_file.txt:

```
192.168.1.1
10.135.135.2
24.50.225.54
```

The result I would like the json would be in this format:

```
{'type': 'RANGE', 'value': '192.168.1.1-192.168.1.1'},
{'type': 'RANGE', 'value': '10.135.135.2-10.135.135.2'},
{'type': 'RANGE', 'value': '24.50.225.54-24.50.225.54'}
```

The result I am getting is only the json dump of only the last value:

```
{'type': 'RANGE', 'value': '24.50.225.54-24.50.225.54'}
```

Comment: You aren't assigning the result of `json.dumps(gateway_dict)` anywhere, so it gets discarded. The `print()` at the end will print only the last value of `gateway_dict` from the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current loop overwrites the values on each iteration of the loop because of the same keys.
Instead, you could have something like this:

```
 with open ('example_file.txt', 'r') as ip_list: #provide the path of the local file that stores the ip addresses
        ip_address = [line.rstrip() for line in ip_list] # Puts the ips in a list 

    gateway_dict = {}
    gateway_dict['record'] = [] # Doesn't have to be 'record' can be something more meaningful
    for each_ip in ip_address:
        gateway_dict['record'].append({
            'type': 'RANGE',
            'value': each_ip + '-' + each_ip
        })
        json.dumps(gateway_dict)
```

Based on the format you said you needed you might need to play around with the json.dumps command. But this should give you your desired output:

```
for item in gateway_dict['record']:
    print(item)
```